Subfiles with a special command in each
I have a document with, for example, 3 subfiles. I want to define a new command that works only in one of my subfiles and will be unknown in other subfiles.
Can you please help me, how to do it?
My preamble is the simplest:
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article} 
\usepackage{subfiles}
\begin{document}
\subfile{one.tex}
\subfile{two.tex}
\subfile{three.tex}
\end{document}


You can keep the definition into that particular subfile only within \bgroup...\egroup, i.e.,
\bgroup%%placed at the start of the subfile

\newcommand{\testcmd}{...definition...}

... content of subfile

\egroup%%placed at the end of the subfile

so the tag \testcmd works only for that particular subfile only.
As you didn't provide any details, this suggestion based on my assumption only

Thank you very much, it works perfectly!

Dear Mady, can you please also help with a very similar question: how to use some \usepackage in one subfile and make it invisible in other subfiles? I think that \bgroup environment will not work, since it is after \begin{document}. Thanks in advance!

@ХранительРощи Please post your preamble part, i.e., from \documentclass to \end{document},  to help you in a better way,

I edited my question. So, for example, is it possible to add physics package to one.tex file and make it not added to the two.tex? Thanks in advance.

Sorry, I think it's not possible and will keep in mind for this, and get back you in future. Also, please make this requirement as a separate post, so some experts will look into that

Understand. But anyway, thank you again for your wonderful answer before!

You can omit \bgroup and egroup, since subfiles are loaded within a group, so definitions stay local.

@gernot Thanks for your note, will take care

This is just to clarify some points, as the original problem seems to have been solved.

The \subfile command loads files within a group, so local definitions within the file stay local. It is not necessary to add further groups (braces, \bgroup/\egroup, \begingroup/\endgroup) in the subfile.

Command definitions in the document body of a subfile will be executed each time the document is processed, either standalone or when loaded by \subfile.

Command definitions in the preamble of a subfile are only executed when treating the subfile as the main file, i.e., when LaTeXing it directly and not loading it via \subfile.
Exception: If you specify the option v1 when loading the subfiles package (\usepackage[v1]{subfiles}), definitions in the preamble will be treated like definitions in the document body and are active no matter how the subfile is processed.


Here is an example for illustration. Suppose we have the three files main.tex, one.tex and two.tex as follows (one.tex and two.tex are identical except for the filename mentioned in the macros).
% main.tex
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{subfiles}
\begin{document}
\subfile{one.tex}
\subfile{two.tex}
\end{document}

% one.tex
\documentclass[main]{subfiles}
\newcommand\onlyThisMain{Only defined if one.tex is LaTeXed as main file.}
\begin{document}
\newcommand\onlyHere{Only defined in one.tex, no matter how it is used.}
\onlyThisMain\ \onlyHere
\end{document}

% two.tex
\documentclass[main]{subfiles}
\newcommand\onlyThisMain{Only defined if two.tex is LaTeXed as main file.}
\begin{document}
\newcommand\onlyHere{Only defined in two.tex, no matter how it is used.}
\onlyThisMain \onlyHere
\end{document}

If you run LaTeX on one.tex and two.tex directly, all commands are correctly defined.
If you run LaTeX on main.tex, it will give two undefined control sequence errors for the two uses of \onlyThisMain, but will expand \onlyHere correctly in both files.
If you add the option v1 when loading subfiles.sty and process main.tex, all commands are defined, no errors.
